# Nullpointer injecting a bean when creating a job via quartz

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, quartz-scheduler

The context is the next:

I have a web app using Spring 2.5 and Struts 1.1
I create a job dynamically in an Action using Quartz:

```
JobDetailBean jobDetail = new JobDetailBean();
        jobDetail.setBeanName("foo");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("idFeed","foo");
        map.put("idSite","foo");
        jobDetail.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        jobDetail.setJobClass(FeedJob.class);
        jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet();

        CronTriggerBean cronTrigger = new CronTriggerBean();
        cronTrigger.setBeanName("foo");
        String expression = " * * * * * *"; 
        cronTrigger.setCronExpression(expression);
        cronTrigger.afterPropertiesSet();

        // add to schedule
        scheduler.scheduleJob((JobDetail) jobDetail, cronTrigger);
```

scheduler is a org.quartz.Scheduler injected in the Action.

The class FeedJob has the method executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) which is the code the job has to run:

```
public class FeedJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    private FeedBL feedBL;

    public void setFeedBL(FeedBL feedBL) {this.feedBL = feedBL;}

    public FeedJob() {}

    public String idFeed;
    public String idSite;  

      public String getIdFeed() {
        return idFeed;
    }

    public void setIdFeed(String idFeed) {
        this.idFeed = idFeed;
    }

    public String getIdSite() {
        return idSite;
    }

    public void setIdSite(String idSite) {
        this.idSite = idSite;
    }

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
         try {
            feedBL.sincronizacionProductFeed(idFeed, idSite);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

And when its going to run, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run this line of code:

```
feedBL.sincronizacionProductFeed(idFeed, idSite);
```

The reason is when I'm creating the job in the Action I'm setting the job:

```
jobDetail.setJobClass(FeedJob.class);
```

And Spring doesn't notice about the bean he has already created, so that instance of the FeedJob class hasn't god injected the feedBL class.

Any good idea for solving this problem?
I have tried to give the job the context like this:

```
jobDetail.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
```

But doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290897/injecting-entity-manager-in-a-programatically-managed-quartz-job/28309175#28309175). It solves the same problem you are experiencing.